# Is there a way of nesting two fileinput in python?

Tags: python, file-io

For each line in *fileX* I need to scan all lines of *fileY*.

I tried this:

```
for line in fileinput.input('fileX'):
    do.fun.stuff(line)
          for element in fileinput.input('fileY'):
              process(element,line)
```

But I get:

**RuntimeError: input() already active**

I guess I have to specify that the second instance of *fileinput* is different from the first one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work since `fileinput.input()` [creates a global instance](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input), so you can't call it twice in the manner that you're trying to.

Why not simply:

```
for line in open('fileX'):
    do.fun.stuff(line)
    for element in open('fileY'):
        process(element,line)
```

Comment: I am not very proficient in python and for some reason my understanding is that fileinput is much more efficient for large files than just using open() Thanks @aix

Comment: @pedrosaurio: `fileinput` is designed for a very specific use case that -- from what I can see -- doesn't apply here. I wouldn't expect it to be faster than using `open`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the explicit answer to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7738798/778533) suggested by @CatPlusPlus:

```
import fileinput
fileX = fileinput.FileInput(files='fileX')
fileY = fileinput.FileInput(files='fileY')
for line in fileX:
    do.fun.stuff(line)
          for element in fileY:
              process(element,line)
```

Answer (score 2):

`fileinput.input` uses a global shared instance of `fileinput.FileInput`. Use that class directly, creating two instances, and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using fileinput, you can iterate over multiple files easily as a unit, but it doesn't seem to gain you anything here. Iterate over the contents of the files separately. One nice approach is using `itertools.product`:

```
import itertools
with open('fileX', 'r') as f1:
    with open('fileY', 'r') as f2:
        for (line, element) in itertools.product(f1, f2):
            process(element, line)
```